# Ogre3d Error: cannot open file OgreMain_d.lib

Tags: visual-c++, linker, compiler-errors, ogre3d

```
Error   2   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OgreMain_d.lib'    C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Code\C++\Test\ogrevcpp\ogrevcpp\LINK   ogrevcpp
```

This is the error I get when trying to build an Ogre3D application (with steps followed from [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Visual+Studio)).

I've followed everything to the T, yet I still get the error. It honestly shouldn't be happening. I've also followed everything from [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Installing+the+Ogre+SDK).

**Edit**

What's happening is there are two different files, one is meant for release, the other is meant for debug. I need the one for debug mode to compile properly (which is `OgreMain_d.lib`).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I figured out what the problem was - I was using the incorrect binaries; there was a few releases which were meant for Visual C++, and one which was meant for MinGW, along with a few other compilers. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your library paths to make sure that the path where OgreMain_d.lib lives is part of the library path.

Comment: by library path do you mean environment variables?

Comment: Well, only if your Visual Studio project also uses environment variables. Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Check your linker search paths in there. What do they specify?

Comment: I have it specified as a search path, yet my intellisense doesn't pick up the actual references. One of the Macros I'm using, `$(OGRE_HOME)` has referenced an incorrect path. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the library for Debug mode is not present in the lib folder. Try putting two different libraries folder for each Assembly mode in Visual Studio. Go to ProjectProperties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories on Right hand. Make sure to check the Configuration Dropdown on the top.